# Отправить с текущей формы ajax запрос

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, thymeleaf

У меня есть таблица с множеством форм.
Вот мой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr th:if="${records.empty}">
        <td colspan="5"> No Records Available </td>
    </tr>
    <tr th:fragment="entity-row" th:each="record : ${records}">
        <form id="subscription_order_form"  th:action="@{/changeElementTable}" method="post">
            <td><input th:value="${record.id}" name="id"  ></td>
            <td><input th:value="${record.firstName}"  id="firstName" name="firstName" ></td>
            <td><input th:value="${record.lastName}" id="lastName" name="lastName"  ></td>
            <td><input th:value="${record.phoneNumber}" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"  ></td>
            <td><input th:value="${record.email}" id="email" name="email"  ></td>
            <td><input th:value="${record.id}"  id="idRepeat" type="hidden" name="idRepeat" ></td>
            <td><button id="button">Отправить</button></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <th></th>
    </tbody>

</table>

<script>
$("#subscription_order_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    editAjax();
})
function editAjax() {
    $(':input').removeAttr('readonly');
    var form_data = $('#subscription_order_form').serialize();

    
    $.ajax({
        url : '/changeElementTable',
        type: 'POST',
        data:form_data,

        success : function(responce) {



        },
        error : function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня данные отправляются сразу со всех форм на бэкенд. Как сделать чтобы данные отправлялись с той формы где стоит курсор на любом из её инпутов ?

Comment: Я бы это делал иначе. Определил бы кнопки как button, и по id назначил обработчики по отдельности на каждую форму.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен если вам до сих пор нужен ответ, но как-то так...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // make sure the code runs after page loaded
    $(function() {
        $("button:button").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var currentForm = $(this).parents('form');
            var currentRow = $(this).parents('tr');
            $.ajax({
                url: currentForm.prop('action'),
                type: currentForm.prop('method'),
                data: currentRow.find('input').serialize(),
                success: function(responce) {
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form th:action="@{/changeElementTable}" method="post">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!--/*/
        <tr th:if="${records.empty}">
            <td colspan="5"> No Records Available </td>
        </tr>
        /*/-->
        <tr th:fragment="entity-row" th:each="record : ${records}">
            <td><input th:value="${record.id}" name="id"></td>
            <td><input th:value="${record.firstName}" name="firstName"></td>
            <td><input th:value="${record.lastName}" name="lastName"></td>
            <td><input th:value="${record.phoneNumber}" name="phoneNumber"></td>
            <td><input th:value="${record.email}" name="email"></td>
            <td><input th:value="${record.id}" type="hidden" name="idRepeat"></td>
            <td><button type="button">Отправить</button></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

По порядку:

1. версия JQuery вы использовали очень старая; используйте новою.
2. убедитесь код запускается только когда страница загружена
3. просто добавте один обработчик на все кнопки
4. используйте родителей кнопки которая нажата
5. вам не нужна HTML форма в цикле
6. не используйте `id` HTML атрибут в цикле